# how to convert response fetched from an excel download API into Json format

Tags: java, json, api, response

I have an API which gives me the response in format as displayed in the attached image. I have tried it to read via inputstreamresponse, but then that gives me corrupted file error quite often.

So planning to try it via json. Mean convert the below response into json format and then read the values from that response. Not sure how to take initial steps on that.

[image: ExceldownloadAPIResponse]

Comment: inputStreamResponse = httpRequest.getHttpRequest(url, oktaJWTToken, puid); 
byte[] responseAsInputStreamByte = new byte[inputStreamResponse.available()];
inputStreamResponse.read(responseAsInputStreamByte);
File targetFileForInputStream = new File(filetowrite);
Files.write(responseAsInputStreamByte, targetFileForInputStream);
inputStreamResponse.close();

This was used earlier to write the above data into excel

Answer (score -1):

i think what you need to do is look into a package like Apache POI. https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

you can take your stream that contains the XLSX file and send it to Apache POI and then once Apache POI class consumes the stream and gives you back an object that is effectively a XLSX file you can then do stuff with it.

Comment: This link does not have info on how to convert API response into an Excel